# Static CSS files not updating/loading in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

**Problem:** None of the changes I'm making to my CSS files are being applied to my HTML pages. And when I try and make new HTML/CSS files I get errors when I inspect the page in developer mode. The errors are saying they can't find my CSS files.

Exact error when I inspect my page in developer mode

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/other.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

**Background:**
I'm creating a basic image editing site using django, html/css, and injecting JS to apply some filters to images. Previously I was able to make changes and they were reflected in the page, but now I can even delete my css file and it still uses an older version.

**Things I've tried:**

1. Gone into settings cleared browser cache
2. Disabled caching in developer mode
3. appended the version of css file ?v1.1 to force a rest (caused the 404 error from above)
4. Run collectstatic in terminal
5. Cleared cache opened site in private window
6. Watched several youtube vids on setting up static file dir and I think its correct. At some point in time my css was loading and updating as I made changes.

**Directory Layout**

[image]

These are my settings

**Settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Image_API',
    'rest_framework',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Image_API.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), '../static')
```

**Urls.py File**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Image_API import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.upload2, name='upload'),
    path('upload/', views.upload2, name='upload'),
    path('other/', views.other),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root =settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**How my HMTL Files refrence css**

I have load static at the top of the page and have my link to the css in the header tag.

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/style.css' %}">
```

Comment: Do you get the 404 if you remove the question mark from the href="{% static '/css/style.css?' %}">  By the error it looks like it is URL encoding it to %3F which is being misunderstood

Comment: The other thing that struck me was - do you really want '../static' in your settings? Won't that take it one dir up from the BASE_DIR?

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` does not match shown folder structure - it is not `staticfiles`. Note, `BASE_DIR` is already `.parent.parent` so if I'm not mistaken `STATIC_ROOT` with `../` falls out of the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be coming from your `STATIC_URL` setting and or `STATIC_ROOT`. Try changing it to:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

You might also want to check that your **`urls.py`** file is setup correctly:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Restart your server after making these changes just to be sure.

**ps**: `collect static` is run during deployment

Comment: Thank you I tried those things and they didn't work. I will add my urls.py file as well to the problem statement.

Comment: Try opening in your app from an incognito window in the browser. It has worked for me before

Comment: i've tried that as well and it didn't work.

Comment: `it didn't work` means nothing and does not help helping you. Show logs, share specific error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You might have overlooked and updated CSS in /staticfiles/css/
Instead try updating it in /media/css.
staticfiles directory is auto-generated when you run python manage.py collectstatic.
You can try deleting staticfiles directory and run python manage.py collectstatic and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pretty much everything that I could find on the Internet and added this to `settings.py`. It must have been the `STATIC_ROOT`, once I added it, the css worked.

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
MEDIA_URL  = '/mymediafolder/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mymediafolder')
```